# Adding a class in list<> and copying that class again and adding again with some modification

Tags: c#, list, class, collections

Firstly, I am adding my class in list<>:

[image]

And then copying that class to new class and after changing date as per logic saving again in list<>, but date of first element already saved in the list is also being changed.

Look at the following image:

[image]

This is my complete code:

```
           if (Session["CompanyId"] != null)
            {
                
                List<CalendarList> CalendartableList = new List<CalendarList>();
                DateTime cldate = Convert.ToDateTime(CalendarList.DateDue);
                CalendarList.CompanyId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["CompanyId"]);
                CalendarList.Category = 15;
                CalendarList.Status = 1;
                CalendarList.Identifier = 232;
                CalendarList.Quarter = 5;
                CalendarList.IsCompleted = false;
                CalendarList.CalendarGUID = CalendarList.Description;
                CalendartableList.Add(CalendarList);

                DateTime po_Date = cldate;
                int pi_Count = 0;

                while (po_Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
                {
                    pi_Count += 1;
                    switch (CalendarList.Interval)
                    {
                        case "Weekly":
                            {
                                po_Date = cldate.AddDays(7 * pi_Count);
                                break;
                            }

                        case "Biweekly":
                            {
                                po_Date = cldate.AddDays(14 * pi_Count);
                                break;
                            }

                        case "Monthly":
                            {
                                po_Date = cldate.AddMonths(1 * pi_Count);
                                break;
                            }

                        default:
                            {
                                po_Date = cldate.AddMonths(3 * pi_Count);
                                break;
                            }
                    }
                    if (po_Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
                    {
                        CalendarList newlist = new CalendarList();
                        newlist = CalendarList;
                        newlist.DateDue = po_Date.ToString();
                        CalendartableList.Add(newlist);
                    }
                }
```

Is there any other way to achieve the same?

Comment: You have to create a copy. You're first creating a new CalendarList which isn't actually a copy, and then throwing it away without ever touching it. You replace it with the original object. Instead, create an actual complete copy (I would give CalendarList a Clone() method as Steve suggests). On a slight tangent, I would urge you to make the `DateDue` property (or field?) a `DateTime` instead of a string, and only convert it to string when you need to display it to the user.

Comment: Try to use the correct terminology. You don’t add classes to a list and you don’t copy classes. You are copying and adding *objects*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to remember is that you are adding a `reference` to your `object`, not a copy of that object, to the list. The simplest fix is to add a `.Clone()` method to your `object` to take a copy of it's self and create that as a new `object`. The cloned copy can be modified independent of the original.

Answer (score 2):

Is `CalendarList` a `class` (maybe you show this in one of your images, but I can't see them)? If so, then it is a [Reference Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types).

> There are two kinds of types in C#: reference types and value types. Variables of reference types store references to their data (objects), while variables of value types directly contain their data. With reference types, two variables can reference the same object; therefore, operations on one variable can affect the object referenced by the other variable. With value types, each variable has its own copy of the data, and it is not possible for operations on one variable to affect the other (except in the case of in, ref and out parameter variables; see in, ref and out parameter modifier).

So, when you call `newlist = CalendarList` you're not copying the values from `CalendarList` to `newlist`, you're setting `newlist` to refer to the exact same object as `CalendarList`. When you modify the object through the `newlist` variable, you will "see" those modifications through the `CalendarList` variable since they both reference the same object.

If you want two different objects, you'll have to manually copy the values from `CalendarList` to `newlist`.

```csharp
CalendarList newlist = new CalendarList
{
   CompanyId = CalendarList.CompanyId,
   Category = CalendarList.Category
   //etc, etc...
}
```

Note that you will encounter similar behavior if the properties of the `CalendarList` class are also reference types. In my example above, `newlist.Category` references the exact same object as `CalendarList.Category`. So, modifications to `Category` through `newlist` will be visible in `CalendarList.Category`.